# PHP Convert to JSON Object

Tags: php, json, encode

I have an associative array that I need to convert to a very specific JSON string. Currently my array looks like this:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'data' => array(
            'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5
        ),
        array(
            'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5
        )
    )
);
```

this JSON encodes as:

```
[{"data":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5},"0":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}}]
```

I need the JSON to look like this:

```
{"data":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}]}
```

Keep in mind that this is a representation on my array and that it can vary in size. Currently it has two records but most likely it will have more.

**How do I encode my array to match my requirement?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(
       'data' => array(
        0=>array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5),
        1=>array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5)
        )
);
```

For me this produces:

```
{"data":[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}]}
```